# Splitting name column with multiple delimiters

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, text-parsing

I'm trying to split a name column (`fullname`) with the format `lastname, firstname` into two separate columns in MySQL using:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ',', 1), ' ', -1) as firstname, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ',', 2), ' ', -1) as lastname FROM tablename;
```

This works on *most* names. However, a name like "Del Torres Jr, Marcelo" shows up as

```
--------------------
lastname | firstname
--------------------   
JR       | Marcelo  
--------------------
```

How to I need to alter my statement to capture all of a name after the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ',',  1) AS firstname 
      ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ',', -1) AS lastname
FROM table
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/33343)

I can't tell what you're trying to do with the match against `' '` but if you're just trying to trim whitespace you can use `TRIM()` on those values.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```
  SELECT  
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ' ,', 1) as lastname ,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ' ,', -1) as firstname
  FROM event;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2fb18/1)

and in your query you should change -1 to 1 like that

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,',', 1),' ', -1) as firstname, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,',', 2),' ', 1) as lastname 
                                                             ^--this should be 1
FROM tablename;
```